# Reference cell value from different home computer within same network

Tags: excel

Trying to grab a cell value from a book/sheet on another home PC

Tried following cell formula, getting `#REF!` error. Using the IP4 address from source machine network properties.

```
='\\192.168.1.28\C:\Users\MASTER\Desktop\[SOURCE.xlsm]SOURCE'!$I$2
```

Expected value from cell `I2` of source machine/book/sheet

Comment: Before Excel has a snowball's chance in the microwave at getting to that data, you'd need to [setup the network share](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/windows-network-sharing/lesson7/) and make sure there aren't any programs like antivirus and or firewalls getting in the way on either machine.

Comment: I tried playing around with the sharing options, but still no luck. Didn’t think it would be such a PiTA :)

Comment: it can be, it kinda depends on which versions of windows all the home PCs are running; but once you can open a network folder and drag it to your desk top you know the connection is working, then it's just a matter of using the same path that the folder is pointed at typically `='\\ComputerA\C\Users\MASTER\Desktop\[Source.xlsm]SOURCE'!$I$2` or you could also map a network drive to \\ComputerA\C. Although even when you do get it working unless you're running Office 365 you're probably going to run into file locking issues if you try to do anything non trivial

Comment: You may want to take a long hard look at your use case and see if there isn't maybe a better software tool to do what you're asking Excel to do.

Comment: Will do that. Thanks you so much

Comment: They’re both W10 machines which seems to make it more complicated than W7 when it comes to sharing. Homegroup features are non-existent it appears. I did forget to mention that anytime destination file is opened, source file will be opened prior to it.

Comment: that's kinda to be expected, the only way to know what the contents of a file are is to read it; regardless if you read it directly or use a chain of third party sources to read it indirectly. The best performance you can hope for is to cache a smaller portion of the file you care about (which is basically what excel does internally) and then you only need to reopen the file if the modified date changes; however with files hosted on a network path excel tends to drop some of its internal assumptions about if the cashed data is stale and typically just re-ups on open.

Comment: This is also why if the network is down and the referenced file on the host changes, the client file will still show old data until it can reconnect to the source